# How far away can my flyback diode be from my inductor?

Tags: inductor, flyback

I have a relay that turns on a dc valve that is connected to it by an electrical socket. Will there be adverse effects if I put my flyback diode near the relay, leaving about 12-18 inches of wire from the plug to the inductor?

[image]

Comment: In fact, the ideal place is at the switch, not the inductor.  Placing it on the connector would seem to be the better of available solutions.

Comment: It is standard practice to suppress transient voltages at source by connecting flyback diodes across DC coils and RC snubbers or MOVs across AC coils of relays and valve solenoids.

Answer (score 1):

A primary purpose of a snubber/clamp diode is to protect the switch from high voltages. In your case the switch is your relay. Since the wires between the inductive element and the relay also themselves have inductance, you may want to protect your switch from that inductance as well. Thus putting your snubber/clamp diode next to the relay makes sense.

There is a drawback to placing the snubber/clamp diode far away from the inductive element however. That is EMI. When the inductive element discharges, it is discharging through the long wires. These wires potentially may radiate EMI. Using twisted pair between the switch and the inductive element will reduce EMI radiating from these wires. Depending on the particulars, EMI may or may not be an concern.

Comment: The "inductive element discharging" produces no emissions in and of itself; it is wholly a consequence of the switch activity, both rise and fall.  If a snubber is needed in the circuit, it is best placed in the same location as the clamp diode: at the switch.

Comment: If the wires that come with my valve are not twisted pair what other things can I do to reduce EMI from the long wires?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, flyback diodes for relay coils as well as valve solenoids are to be located right at the coils themselves, in order to prevent long wires from behaving as antennas for EMI.

It's possible to obtain relays / relay sockets and solenoid valve plugs that have in-built flyback diodes.

Otherwise, it should be ensured that the flyback diodes are wired as close to relay coils and valve solenoids as possible.

[image]

In this example, the flyback diode across the relay coil protects the transistor and the one across the valve solenoid protects the relay contacts.

Comment: Surely you mean relay contacts, not coils? But then how would solenoids make sense?

Comment: It is standard practice to suppress transient voltages at source by connecting flyback diodes across DC coils and RC snubbers or MOVs across AC coils of relays and valve solenoids.

Comment: Common practice, yes; but practice follows from theory, not the other way around. The source is the switch.

Comment: The flyback voltage spikes are generated by the relay coils / valve solenoids and certainly not the switches.

Comment: The coil inductance is a necessary but not sufficient condition. Consider what happens if the coil is driven by fixed (e.g. variable DC) voltage. Does flyback occur? Why or why not? Consider the switch: what is the definition of a switch? A two-terminal element whose effective resistance changes over a vast range (say, more than three decades). What effect does a varying resistance have on the dynamics of a loop containing the switch and a complex reactive element?